# Reinstall python packages after homebrew python@3.8 update

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I have recently updated **python** to **python@3.8** via homebrew.

I then noticed that my python scripts were unable to link to the global python packages that I had previously installed with pip (packages installed globally and not within a virtual environment).

This has sent me down the rabbit hole of understanding how python is set up on macos and I have several questions.

1. pip installed by homebrew will now install all packages in **/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages**.

   - Does that mean I need to reinstall all my python packages that used to live (and still are) in **/usr/local/lib/python3.7**? Should I remove the latter directory after? (For that matter I can see I have also a **/usr/local/lib/python3.6** directory)
   - What's the efficient way of managing this in the future when the next python update comes along? Virtual envs per project (I'm not very familiar with the use of virtual envs)?
2. When I run
   `brew list | grep python` I get the following list

```
python
python3
python@3.8
```

I can see python@3.8 is correctly symlinked as **/usr/local/bin/python3** but I don't know what the python and python3 in the above list are since looking at **/usr/local/Cellar** I can see that I have an empty **/usr/local/Cellar/python** directory and a **/usr/local/Cellar/python3** directory that is symlinked to it. Can I juste remove these two folders?

3. Finally, looking into all this, I was surprised to discover a python3 executable living in **/usr/bin**.
   Looking into the **sys.path** when I execute **/usr/bin/python3**, I can see it's some sort of python installed by Xcode since it's looking for libraries in various Xcode.app directories.
   Since my **/usr/local/bin** is at the top of my PATH envt variable, this python3 will never be called but I wonder why I'd need it at all and whether I can just get rid of it.

I suppose the answer to a lot of these questions is to use virtual environments, which I've miraculously avoided doing for so long... Would love some help understanding the above though.

**EDIT:** Running `brew info python` or `brew info python3` returns the same thing

```sh
python@3.8: stable 3.8.3 (bottled)
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.3_2 (4,268 files, 65.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-07-12 at 23:19:08
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/python@3.8.rb
```

Comment: This is not related to virtual environments. A new Python installation is a new Python installation, full stop. It does not (and due to binary incompatibility should not!) use packages from another Python installation. You have to reinstall the package that you need. As for cleaning up Python installations – use ``brew doctor`` and the various other ``brew`` commands. If ``brew`` does not remove something (e.g. ``usr/bin/python3``) there is a good chance you should not do so either.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a system running Python 3.9

I had initially not run the final command (only the `--dry-run`), as everything seemed fine, but *as suggested during the installation*, using `brew link` to clobber **and create** new symlinks was needed.

```
% brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.9
Would remove:
% brew link --overwrite python@3.9
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1... 23 symlinks created
%
```

---

As suggested by [**MisterMiyagi** in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi), this was uncovered via `brew doctor`

```
...
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@3.9
```

Comment: `brew doctor` helped me fix my issues too